# Retrieving various hashes from Redis in Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

How could one retrieve various hashes from Redis in Node.js through [node-redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)? The best way of retrieving various hashes seems to be [pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929202/most-efficient-way-to-get-several-hashes-in-redis) but I have not found how to use them in Node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve that using the `multi` command to queue the hash retrieval commands:

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(),
    multi_queue;

multi_queue = client.multi();
...
for (key in keys) {
  multi_queue.hgetall(key);
}

multi_queue.exec(function (err, replies) {
  console.log("MULTI got " + replies.length + " replies");
  replies.forEach(function (reply, index) {
    console.log("Reply " + index + ": " + reply.toString());
  });
});
```

Comment: Just to mention a few typos in the "multi_queue" variable name, sometimes "multi_queue", "multiqueue", or "multi", all for the same thing.