# Redis-python setting multiple key/values in one operation

Tags: redis, redis-py

Currently I use the basic `mset` feature to store a key/value;

```
from common.redis_client import get_redis_client
cache = get_redis_client()
for k,v in some_dict.items():
   kw = {'key': value}
   cache.mset(kw) 

#later:
   cache.get('key')
```

I store each key/value separatly (not in one json for example) Since storing the whole dict would turn it into a string and would require me to serialize/deserialize on storing and retrieving and I really need access to seperate key/values.

**My question::** is there a way I can `mset` multiple key/values at once? Instead of multiple writes to the redis db? And vice-versa can I have multiple reads (get) in one access? (and Yes - I have a lot of redis activity going on and with heavy load. I do care about this)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**updated** after Agis comment

If you use [Redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py), which is currently the recommended Redis client for python, you can use the pipelining which does exactly what you want. Here is a simple example:

```
>>> r = redis.Redis(...)
>>> r.set('bing', 'baz')
>>> # Use the pipeline() method to create a pipeline instance
>>> pipe = r.pipeline()
>>> # The following SET commands are buffered
>>> pipe.set('foo', 'bar')
>>> pipe.get('bing')
>>> # the EXECUTE call sends all buffered commands to the server, returning
>>> # a list of responses, one for each command.
>>> pipe.execute()
[True, 'baz']
```

I don't know which redis client you are using, but either it supports the pipelining, or you should consider switching to redis-py.

Have a look at [redis documentation about pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining); it explains that you can expect a x5 performance boost -but also that you must not perform too important bulk operations (10 000 operations at each execution is OK).

Comment: Note that pipelining will still make the same number of writes. However it will save you from roundtrip time: http://redis.io/topics/pipelining

Comment: Also `MULTI` and `EXEC` is about *Transactions*, not pipelining.

Comment: Thanks! works like charm for sets - how can I aggregate gets with pipeline? would it return a list? a dict? 
currently I have:
```kw = {}
for key in keys:
        
        kw[key] = redis_cache.get(key)

    return kw```

How could I use pipe line with that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929202/most-efficient-way-to-get-several-hashes-in-redis

Answer (score 8):

Since you seem to be looking for storing a dictionary, I see two more possible solutions:

1. Use `HMGET`/`HMSET` commands. This does allow to get and set multiple individual keys from a dictionary. The disadvantage is that it's all on one key, so if you plan for key expiration of individual dict entries - as is common with caching - this will not work for you.
2. I decided to use `MGET` and `MSET` commands. This allows to set multiple keys at once and also retrieve them at once. You already used the `MSET` (multi set) command in your example, but only set ONE value...

Your example might work this way:

`cache.mset(some_dict)`

You will want to add a common prefix to your dictionary entries:

`cache.mset({'prefix:' + k:v for k,v in some_dict.items()})`

This way you will be able to retrieve your dict entries with `MGET` by key. If you don't know the keys upfront you can run a `KEYS` command with a "prefix:*" wildcard before.