# Is there a command in Redis for HASH data structure similar to MGET?

Tags: redis

I need to get in one call all data fields for a set of known REDIS hash keys. I've used MGET for string keys such as :

MGET key [key ...]

Available since 1.0.0.

Time complexity: O(N) where N is the number of keys to retrieve.

Returns the values of all specified keys. For every key that does not hold a string value or does not exist, the special value nil is returned. Because of this, the operation never fails.

HMGET only brings all fields for one key. I need many keys all fields by key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there MGET analog for Redis hashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329408/is-there-mget-analog-for-redis-hashes)

Answer (score 1):

There is no command like that, redis hashes work within the hash, so HMGET work inside one hash and give all the fields in that hash. There is **no way to access all the fields in multiple hashes at ones**.

However you can user several HMGET on each hash and get all the fields. you can pipeline these commands to execute in a one go.

**Option 1**
Ex. implementation in pseudo code

```
Pipeline p
List<String> = p.hgetall('key1', fields...); 
List<String> = p.hgetall('key2', fields...);
List<String> = p.hgetall('key3', fields...);
p.exec();
```

**Option 2**
Other option is to write a LUA script and call that using EVAL

```
local array = {}
local keys = redis.call('KEYS', '<your pattern>')

for _,key in ipairs(keys) do
    local val = redis.call('HGETALL', key)
    array[#array + 1] = val
end

return array
```

Call the lua sctipt

```
redis-cli EVAL "$(cat test.lua)" 0

1) 1) "field1"
   2) "val"
2) 1) "field1"
   2) "val"
   3) "field2"
   4) "val2"
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another answer, there's no built in way but there more workarounds besides a transaction.

### Option 1: use a Lua script (i.e. `EVAL "..." 3 myhash1 myhash2 myhash3 myfield`)

```
local r = {}
while (#KEYS > 0) do
  local k = table.remove(KEYS,1)
  r[#r+1] = redis.call('HGET', k, ARGV[1])
end

return r
```

### Option 2: write a Redis module

Out of scope as a an answer :)